# avoid explicit cast to float?

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, default

Can

```
SELECT CAST(2.083 AS float) AS c
```

be written in a more compact way ?

Something like

```
SELECT 2.083f AS c
```

?

Comment: In brief: no. If you need to explicitly change / define the datatype, you must use `CAST` or `CONVERT` - no "shortcuts" available

Comment: How do you know the datatype of SELECT 2.083 AS c ?

Comment: You don't - it could be either REAL/FLOAT, or it could be DECIMAL - but you cannot really tell in T-SQL. You can assign this value to both `FLOAT` or `DECIMAL` columns.

Comment: I'd say use `CAST()`, since it's the ANSI SQL way.

Comment: Just to give light to the other side, I'd say use `CONVERT`, it's more flexible. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these comments are true ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid an explict `CAST` to `float`, specify a [floating point constant expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql):

```
--these both return float with precision 53
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT CAST(2.083 AS float) AS c;';
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT 2.083E0 AS c;';

--without scientific notation, the constant is interpreted as numeric(4,3)
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT 2.083 AS c;';
```